# Area of triangle using double integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral

I have one (rather simple) problem, but I'm stuck and can't figure out what I'm constantly doing wrong. I need to calculate area of triangle with points at $(0,0)$, $(t,0)$, $(t,\frac{t}{2})$. In other words triangle under function $y=\frac{x}{2}$, for $x\in [0,t]$ I thought it is calculated with
$$ \int_0^t \int_0^\frac{t}{2} dudv$$
But it turns out that this equals to $\frac{t^2}{2}$, when obviously this area is $\frac{t\times\frac{t}{2}}{2} = \frac{t^2}{4}$.
What am I doing wrong here?
I need to calculate it this way, not with single integral, or geometrically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral that you actually computed corresponds to the area of a rectangle. You should actually compute$$\int_0^t\int_0^{\frac x2}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Silly me. Names for variables were different in my notes, so I got confused. Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake, the bounds on the inner integral should not be constant:
$$
\int_0^t \int_0^{v/2} dudv
 = \int_0^t \frac{v}{2} dv
 = \left. \frac{v^2}{4} \right|_0^t = \frac{t^2}{4}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. That solved it